# Should blog post with comments be a static page NextJS

Tags: next.js

I have a blog page with posts stored in database. I allow users to suggest changes to post and comment it. The path is `/app/posts/[name]/page.tsx`. Should I use static rendering (https://nextjs.org/learn/dashboard-app/static-and-dynamic-rendering)? I read that it should improve seo a lot. I would appreciate help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many pros and cons to use static site generation of next js:

**Pros**

- Helps in SEO: Search Engine Optimization helps your website rank higher on search engines like Google.
- In your Next.js application, search engines can easily crawl SSG-indexed pages because they are just HTML files.
- SSG works better with Content Delivery Networks (CDNs), which means you can serve your static page from distributed servers worldwide, which improves your website’s global performance.
- Since the web pages are pre-generated, the server is not expected to process each request sent by a user, which improves your website’s scalability.

**Cons**

- With SSG, you cannot effectively change or make real-time updates on your website because any update will require a rebuild, causing delays.
- The build process can become time-consuming on websites with numerous pages.
- If your Next.js applications require authentication and logic, it can be challenging to use SSG.

As a next js developer myself, I'd recommend using ssg for any data that doesn't need an update on every client view and even If it needs an update, use `revalidate` option.

And for any data that gets updated alot and the client should always get the latest version, I'd recommend using ssr coupled with react's own client side rendering.

Comment: do I understand correctly that if I use static site generation then if a user adds a comment, it will not be visile until I rebuild the page? And here the revalidate options helps to rebuild the page? In my case I care about SEO, is SSR recommended in that case? The thing is that the comments will change often and the content itself might change for example twice a week.

Comment: @Kernier Just like you've mentioned that the comments will change often, I'd suggest to to use client side rendering for the comments and ssg for content that might change twice a week. The revalidate option will do the regeneration automatically for you. I'd suggest to watch tutorials for `Incremental Static Regeneration` to understand how the revalidate option actually works.